# Usage of "not [adjective] yet" inside a sentence

Tags: writing-style

I have studied the usage of **"(not) yet"** in sentences, but I could not find this specific case:

In the sentence **"The process is not ready yet for this user"** is the usage for **"not [adjective] yet"** correct?

I understand that, if it's used at the end of a sentence (*"The process is not ready yet"*), then it is correct. But I'm wondering whether or not that holds true if the sentence continues after "yet". I know I could rewrite it like:

- *"The process is not yet ready for this user"*
- *"The process is not ready for this user yet"*

but I would also like to know if the first form is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both constructions are correct and mean the same thing, but placing "yet" before the adjective is more usual when the adjective has a complement, whereas when this is not the case, and in particular when a punctuation follows the adjective, it is usual to place "yet" after the adjective. This can be elicited from pages associated to the following [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+not+yet+ready%2Che+is+not+ready+yet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20not%20yet%20ready%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20not%20ready%20yet%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20is%20not%20yet%20ready%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20not%20ready%20yet%3B%2Cc0) .

[not yet ready](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20not%20yet%20ready%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[not ready yet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20not%20ready%20yet%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[image]

However, sentences such as the following may occur and are correct.

- They are not ready yet to take on such tasks.